# qbo3 Batch Import ignores some rows in my spreadsheet

Tags: qbo3

Using the qbo3 Batch Import, I am uploading a spreadsheet containing my enumerations, along these lines:

| ClassName | Operation | ObjectStatus | Object |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ObjectStatus | Save | Option A | Resolution |
| ObjectStatus | Save | Option B | Resolution |
| ObjectStatus | Save | Option C | Resolution |
| ObjectStatus | Save | SubOption 1 | Resolution.Option A |
| ObjectStatus | Save | SubOption 2 | Resolution.Option B |

This incorrectly sets the `ImportFileQueue.Object` column to `Resolution` (or `Resolution.Option A`), instead of setting `ObjectStatus.Object` to `Resolution`.

Reviewing the [Batch Engine documentation](https://github.com/quandis/qbo3-Documentation/wiki/import-api#batch-engine), I corrected this issue by changing the `Object` column as follows:

| ClassName | Operation | ObjectStatus | Parameters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ObjectStatus | Save | Option A | Object=Resolution |
| ObjectStatus | Save | Option B | Object=Resolution |
| ObjectStatus | Save | Option C | Object=Resolution |
| ObjectStatus | Save | SubOption 1 | Object=Resolution.Option A |
| ObjectStatus | Save | SubOption 2 | Object=Resolution.Option A |
| ObjectStatus | Save | SubOption 1 | Object=Resolution.Option B |
| ObjectStatus | Save | SubOption 2 | Object=Resolution.Option B |

This successfully bound `Object` to the `ObjectStatus` table, but for some reason, 2 of my `SubOption` rows were ignored by the import.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; add a column called `SetPropertiesLookup` with a value of `FALSE` for every row:

| ClassName | Operation | ObjectStatus | Parameters | SetPropertiesLookup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ObjectStatus | Save | Option A | Object=Resolution | False |
| ObjectStatus | Save | Option B | Object=Resolution | False |
| ObjectStatus | Save | Option C | Object=Resolution | False |
| ObjectStatus | Save | SubOption 1 | Object=Resolution.Option A | False |
| ObjectStatus | Save | SubOption 2 | Object=Resolution.Option A | False |
| ObjectStatus | Save | SubOption 1 | Object=Resolution.Option B | False |
| ObjectStatus | Save | SubOption 2 | Object=Resolution.Option B | False |

---

This behavior is an artifact of `ImportFileQueue`'s build-in deduping logic: users frequently attempt to upload spreadsheets with duplicate rows, which can in turn cause invocation of unwanted API calls to third party systems or other such problems.

Uniqueness is determined by a combination of:

- `ClassName`
- `Operation`
- `ParameterXml`: an XML representation of all other columns

Since `Parameters` is a known column, but is not considered part of the unique signature, `ImportFileQueue` considers `SubOption 1` and `SubOption 2` to be duplicates.

Adding the `SetPropertiesLookup` causes `ImportFileQueue` to ignore the deduplication checks.